# Embedded C Passing a String to function

Tags: c, string, winavr

I'm trying to send an array of characters in C, byte by byte to an output for a microcontroller. I'm using the following code:

```
int main() {
...
   LogOutput("Hello World!");
}

void LogOutput(char *msg) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(msg); i++) {
        USART0_TX(msg[i]);              // transmit byte
    }
}
```

However, this only sends the first two letters "He" --- does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the `sizeof` operator, and getting the size of the *datatype*, not the length of the string. Use `strlen` to get the length of a string (include `string.h` for `strlen` and other string manipulation functions).

Comment: Thanks! #include <string.h> as well for n00bs like myself out there!

Comment: fyi, i also found that if you're working with microcontrollers like I am, this won't work with char arrays that contain a 0x00 as the strlen function terminates on a NULL character. best to just pass the length as a separate parameter for those cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
...
   LogOutput("Hello World!");
}

void LogOutput(char *msg) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(msg); i++) {
        USART0_TX(msg[i]);              // transmit byte
    }
}
```